# How to print keys and values of nested dicts in python

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I am wondering how to print out just the team names from this nested dict.

```
{
  "leagueCaption": "Premier League 2016/17", 
  "matchday": 17, 
  "standing": [
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/Chelsea_crest.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 24, 
      "goals": 35, 
      "goalsAgainst": 11, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 43, 
      "rank": 1, 
      "team": "Chelsea", 
      "teamId": 61
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/0a/FC_Liverpool.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 21, 
      "goals": 41, 
      "goalsAgainst": 20, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 37, 
      "rank": 2, 
      "team": "Liverpool", 
      "teamId": 64
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 16, 
      "goals": 36, 
      "goalsAgainst": 20, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 36, 
      "rank": 3, 
      "team": "ManCity", 
      "teamId": 65
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 19, 
      "goals": 38, 
      "goalsAgainst": 19, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 34, 
      "rank": 4, 
      "team": "Arsenal", 
      "teamId": 57
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b4/Tottenham_Hotspur.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 17, 
      "goals": 29, 
      "goalsAgainst": 12, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 33, 
      "rank": 5, 
      "team": "Spurs", 
      "teamId": 73
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 7, 
      "goals": 24, 
      "goalsAgainst": 17, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 30, 
      "rank": 6, 
      "team": "ManU", 
      "teamId": 66
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/c/c9/FC_Southampton.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 1, 
      "goals": 17, 
      "goalsAgainst": 16, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 24, 
      "rank": 7, 
      "team": "Southampton", 
      "teamId": 340
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/8/8b/West_Bromwich_Albion.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 2, 
      "goals": 23, 
      "goalsAgainst": 21, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 23, 
      "rank": 8, 
      "team": "West Bromwich", 
      "teamId": 74
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f9/Everton_FC.svg", 
      "goalDifference": 0, 
      "goals": 21, 
      "goalsAgainst": 21, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 23, 
      "rank": 9, 
      "team": "Everton", 
      "teamId": 62
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/4/41/Afc_bournemouth.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -5, 
      "goals": 23, 
      "goalsAgainst": 28, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 21, 
      "rank": 10, 
      "team": "Bournemouth", 
      "teamId": 1044
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a3/Stoke_City.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -5, 
      "goals": 19, 
      "goalsAgainst": 24, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 21, 
      "rank": 11, 
      "team": "Stoke", 
      "teamId": 70
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Watford.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -8, 
      "goals": 21, 
      "goalsAgainst": 29, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 21, 
      "rank": 12, 
      "team": "Watford", 
      "teamId": 346
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/e/e0/West_Ham_United_FC.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -12, 
      "goals": 19, 
      "goalsAgainst": 31, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 19, 
      "rank": 13, 
      "team": "West Ham", 
      "teamId": 563
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2c/Middlesbrough_FC_crest.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -3, 
      "goals": 16, 
      "goalsAgainst": 19, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 18, 
      "rank": 14, 
      "team": "Middlesbrough", 
      "teamId": 343
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png", 
      "goalDifference": -6, 
      "goals": 23, 
      "goalsAgainst": 29, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 17, 
      "rank": 15, 
      "team": "Foxes", 
      "teamId": 338
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Burnley_FC_badge.png", 
      "goalDifference": -12, 
      "goals": 16, 
      "goalsAgainst": 28, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 17, 
      "rank": 16, 
      "team": "Burnley", 
      "teamId": 328
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bf/Crystal_Palace_F.C._logo_%282013%29.png", 
      "goalDifference": -4, 
      "goals": 28, 
      "goalsAgainst": 32, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 15, 
      "rank": 17, 
      "team": "Crystal", 
      "teamId": 354
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/6/60/AFC_Sunderland.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -13, 
      "goals": 15, 
      "goalsAgainst": 28, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 14, 
      "rank": 18, 
      "team": "Sunderland", 
      "teamId": 71
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/ab/Swansea_City_Logo.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -17, 
      "goals": 20, 
      "goalsAgainst": 37, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 12, 
      "rank": 19, 
      "team": "Swans", 
      "teamId": 72
    }, 
    {
      "crestURI": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a9/Hull_City_AFC.svg", 
      "goalDifference": -22, 
      "goals": 14, 
      "goalsAgainst": 36, 
      "playedGames": 17, 
      "points": 12, 
      "rank": 20, 
      "team": "Hull", 
      "teamId": 322
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking to just print team. If this dict is called response, I thought I could do:

```
team = response['standing']['team']
```

But I can't I am getting an error.

I am running this on flask and here is the python code!

Essentially I am trying to print out an EPL league table!

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import httplib
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index1():
    return render_template('league.html')

@app.route('/League Standing', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_league():
    text = request.form['league']
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
    headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'mytoken', 'X-Response-Control': 'minified'}
    connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions/'+text+'/leagueTable', None, headers)
    response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
    return jsonify(response)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `response['standing'][0]['team']` would yield 'Chelsea' because `response['standing']` is a list, not a dictionary.  Iterate over `response['standing']` and for each `item` you can use `item['team']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line:

```
 teamnames = [r['team'] for r in response['standing'] ]
```

this returns: ['Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'ManCity', 'Arsenal', 'Spurs', 'ManU', 'Southampton', 'West Bromwich', 'Everton', 'Bournemouth', 'Stoke', 'Watford', 'West Ham', 'Middlesbrough', 'Foxes', 'Burnley', 'Crystal', 'Sunderland', 'Swans', 'Hull']

If you want to return the teamname: points  as a list of strings:

```
points=[r['team']+": "+str(r['points']) for r in response['standing']]
```

If you wanted the teamname: points as a dictionary you can use:

```
 points={r['team']:r['points'] for r in response['standing']}
```

Comment: if I wanted to return the teamname: points so that Chelsea: 44 etc.... how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can not access `"team"` as key because `dict["standing"]` holds the `list` value. In order to print all the teams, do:

```
for standing in my_json['standing']:
    print standing['team']
```

where `my_json` holds your `dict` object. In case you want to get the `list` of all teams, you may use *list comprehension* expression as:

```
[standing['team'] for standing in my_json['standing']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
team = response['standing'][0]['team']
```

`[0]`index is used for accessing the first dictionary of `standing` key as multiple dictionaries are present within the `standing` key.